# Complex where/join statement with codeigniter across several tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having issues getting a large `WHERE` statement to function using codeigniters active record.

Below is the code I currently have

```php
public function get_pending_posts($userid){
    $where = "posts.complete = 0 AND poststatuses.contact != 3 AND (poststatuses.poster = $userid OR poststatuses.accepter = $userid)";

    $data = $this->db->select('posts.id AS postid, posts.option, a.gravatar, posts.title,p.firstname AS pfirstname, p.lastname AS plastname, a.firstname AS afirstname, a.lastname AS alastname, poststatuses.contact,poststatuses.modified')
            ->join('users p','poststatuses.poster = p.id')
            ->join('users a','poststatuses.accepter = a.id')
            ->join('posts','poststatuses.postid = posts.id')
            ->where($where)
            ->get('poststatuses');

    $results = array();
    if($data->num_rows()){
        $results['num'] = $data->num_rows();
        $results['requests'] = $data->result();
    }
    else{
        $results['num'] = 0;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

When I call this function I get the following error

```
Column 'complete' in where clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM (`poststatuses`) JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`id` = `poststatuses`.`id` WHERE `complete` = 1 AND `rating` = 0
```

Any idea why CI is converting `posts.complete = 0` to `complete = 0`?

Comment: If you don't want CodeIgniter to mess with your where statement, You'll have to do something like ->where($where, NULL, FALSE) but keep in mind you'll have to sanitize the values yourself. $this->db->escape If I recall correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the third parameter of `where()` method to `FALSE` to prevent CI from adding backticks to `table`/`field` names.

From **[CI doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)**:

> $this->db->where() accepts an optional third parameter. If you set it
>   to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

As follows:

```
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: I changed/added those parameters and I still get the same error. Thoughts?

Comment: The generated SQL query seems odd, first the *asterisk* `SELECT *` which selects all fields, then `complete = 1` instead of `complete = 0`.